# Reload navbar component on every this.$router.push() call

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I developing a login/registration system in my Vue.js app. I want the items in navbar to be updated when I call `this.$router.push('/')`.

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Navbar component:

```
export default {
    name: "Navbar",
    data: function() {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: false,
            currentUser: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAuthInfo: function() {
            this.isLoggedIn = this.auth.isLoggedIn();
            if (this.isLoggedIn) {
                this.currentUser = this.auth.currentUser();
            }
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        this.getAuthInfo();
    },
    updated: function() {
        this.getAuthInfo();
    }
}
```

Here is how I redirect to another page:

```
const self = this;
this.axios
    .post('/login', formData)
    .then(function(data) {
        self.auth.saveToken(data.data.token);
        self.$router.push('/');
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        self.errorMessage = 'Error!';
    });
```

**SUMMARY:** The problem is that `isLoggedIn` and `currentUser` in Navbar don't get updated when I call `self.$router.push('/');`. This means that functions `mounted` and `updated` don't get called. They are updated only after I manually refresh the page.

Comment: I also faced the same problem could not find any solution for this. Used this.$router.go() to refresh component so don't have to manually reload. If you solve this problem let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding `:key="$route.fullPath"` to Navbar component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar :key="$route.fullPath"></Navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <Footer></Footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [from the docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  // called when the route that renders this component has changed,
  // but this component is reused in the new route.
  // For example, for a route with dynamic params `/foo/:id`, when we
  // navigate between `/foo/1` and `/foo/2`, the same `Foo` component instance
  // will be reused, and this hook will be called when that happens.
  // has access to `this` component instance.
},
```

I expect your Navbar component is reused across routes so its `mounted` and `updated` are not called. Try using `beforeRouteUpdate` if you want to do some processing on route change.

Comment: If I place `beforeRouteUpdate` in Navbar component it doesn't get called if I use `self.$router.push('/');`.